# Why can't I use useState in Next JS 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have been facing issues using `useState` inside a `useEffect` for a while, so I decided to create a new project to test some things.

I've just created a new project, and the only thing I've done was change the main `page.tsx` file for this:

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default async function Home() {
  const [a, b] = useState(10)

  useEffect(() => {
    b(20)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        test: {a}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Even with this simple code, I can already reproduce the error I was getting, which is:

> "Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server."

But I'm not using async/await. Only `useEffect` and `useState`. Why is this?

I tried using Next 13 and it did work, but it won't work with the 14th version. The specific version I'm using is the latest: 14.0.4.

Comment: The answers below are indeed correct. However, if your page component requires asynchronous behavior for tasks such as server-side data fetching, you can modify your approach. Move your query or client-only code outside of your page into a separate file that includes the "use client" directive.

Comment: Thnak you all so much!! I've finally understand it and was able to fix my code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove "async" on line 5

So your code may be like that

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const [a, b] = useState(10)

  useEffect(() => {
    b(20)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>test: {a}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's the async function when declaring the Home() component.

Comment: Could you explain why we can't add ASYNC in front of Home()?